# azure search can't import data

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

i'm new to azure search and want to import my documents. I created a container into a blob storage and uploaded the documents to it. Then i tried to import the data to my azure search but it says, that i don't have any containers:
[image]

[image]

Am i doing this wrong?

Comment: It should work, I noticed the UI on my side is different from yours, may be related? https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Q8y.png

Comment: You should connect to exist datasource.